# How to pass literal String array to jsp:attribute

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl, jsp-tags

I have a a JSP attribute in a JSP Tag file and I'm trying to pass it a literal String like {"Something", "Something else"} Is there anyway to do it?

This is the closest I've come but it doesn't work.

from test.tag

```
<%@ attribute name="array" rtexprvalue="true" type="java.lang.String[]" %>
```

from jsp

```
<%
    request.setAttribute("theArray", new String[] {"Something", "Something else"});
%>
<jsp:attribute name="array">${theArray}</jsp:attribute>
```

But the tag file still sees it as a string.

Comment: Which JSP version are you using?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I'm on JSP Spec 2.3 now. Can't get tomcat 10 to work right in NetBeans 14 which is another issue.

Comment: I realized I can just do ${theArray} in the tag file and bypass the attribute. Was hoping to find a way to do it without scriptlets.